# How to update the stored procedure to fetch more columns from the Data source while keeping old data

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a legacy DB. A stored procedure `SC_Total_Alerts_SP` runs and fetches data every week. This has been going on for years. Now the requirements are such that I need to get a few extra columns. These columns are not part of the legacy DB. I know the changes that I need to do to the stored procedure, but my question is that how can I make sure that I do not lose any legacy data.

Query:

```
DECLARE @my_Date DATETIME = GETDATE()

SELECT 
    @my_Date AS Date,
    Title_9691DD10_7211_C835_E3E7_6B38AF8B8104 AS Alert,
    Priority_B930B964_A1C4_0B5A_B2D1_BFBE9ECDC794 AS Priority,
    SDUA.DisplayName AS Name
FROM 
    [ServiceManager].[dbo].[MT_System$WorkItem$Incident] WII
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM [ServiceManager].[dbo].Relationship
     WHERE RelatiONshipTypeId = '15E577A3-6BF9-6713-4EAC-BA5A5B7C4722') ATU ON ATU.SourceEntityId = WII.BaseManagedEntityId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [ServiceManager].[dbo].MT_System$Domain$User SDUA ON SDUA.BaseManagedEntityId = ATU.TargetEntityId 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM [ServiceManager].[dbo].LocalizedText
     WHERE ElementName LIKE '%IncidentSTATUSEnum%'
       AND LanguageCode = 'ENU'
       AND DisplayStringId IS NOT NULL) LTS ON LTS.LTStringId = WII.Status_785407A9_729D_3A74_A383_575DB0CD50ED 
WHERE 
    LTS.ElementName LIKE '%Resolved'
    AND SDUA.DisplayName IS NOT NULL
    AND CreatedDate_6258638D_B885_AB3C_E316_D00782B8F688 > DateAdd(dd, -7, @my_Date)
```

Comment: are you using JOIN to get the extra columns?.

Comment: ok here is my query, I have updated the question with SP Kumar, yes as you can see I am using multiple join, but what I am asking is that Destination table should be updated, but I want to keep legacy data, how can I make sure that the data is not lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way is to put the original query in a WITH statement, then use that derived table and left outer join the new data to it to get the new columns.

Comment: thanks for your input. I'll backup db and give it a go.